# WebBrowser WPF element unable to load web page. Fiddler response: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application holding WebBrowser control.
The navigation URI points to https.
On few machines, with IE 11 installed, the application works fine.

But with the machines that have IE 8 installed, it shows Navigation to the web page was cancelled.
Running Fiddler in parallel, gives error details as:
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

Although, if IE's settings are changed to check SSL and TSL check boxes under settings>security, the application works fine.

What is the solution to make the application work on all machines, regardless of what browser version is installed on the machine?